# Identifing context of clicked item from ItemsControl in code

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have some collection bound to `ItemsControl`. DataTemplate was customized to represent its elements. Now I have to perform some operation on data (one Cell from collection) corresponding to rendered DataTemplate in result of clicking it.

Window's `DataContext` is set to ViewModel containing my collection.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="template"
              DataType="logic:Cell">
    <Ellipse .../>
</DataTemplate>

...

<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource template}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
   ...               
</ItemsControl>
```

I have just started with MVVM pattern for WPF. I'm looking for good pattern to deal with such issue (in MVVM style).

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel, you can use the following snippet...

```
    var v = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyCollection);
    var ci = v.CurrentItem;
    int p = v.CurrentPosition;
```

where 'MyCollection' is the list you have bound to your ItemsControl.  The variable 'ci' will contain an object which can be downcast to the item you need.  The variable 'p' tells the index of where 'ci' is in your collection.

If 'MyCollection' inherits from IList, there are additional goodies you can access as well.

Adding:  check for nulls before referencing